# call a method within react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call my method onModelSelect automatically if there is only 1 item in the `this.props.models` array

If I attach the method to an `onClick` event handler it works, but on it's own I'm unsure of the syntax to use

If I use the syntax

```
this.onModelSelect(model.id))
```

I then get the error:

> setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such
>   as withinrender). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state.

However it does output to console.log

So I am trying to call it like I would with my `onClick` event handler `()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))` but this doesn't output anything to console.log

what is the correct syntax to use to call my method??

```
 export default class App extends Component {
        onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
          this.props.selectModel(modelId);
          this.props.setModelSelected(true);
          console.log('test')
          console.log('modelId',modelId)
        }
        render() {
          return(
            <div>
              {this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => ()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))}
              {this.props.models.map(model =>
                <div onClick={()=> this.onModelSelect(model.id)}>Select Model</div>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
```

Comment: The render method is supposed to turn the component's state into an HTML representation. It cannot change the state, because that could cause an infinite loop (because state changes usually cause a re-rendering). The basic fix is to handle a length of 1 in the parent component (by not displaying the selection in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your parent component by checking if length of state/props of model array is 1 then set state which is you are doing by calling methods provided by props. You can do this when you are setting state of model array or receiving props of model array.

Comment: I do the check in my mapStatetoProps `const modelCheck = getFilteredSelectableModels(state).length === 1 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946319/call-a-method-within-react-render#getFilteredSelectableModels(state)` and then use this `{this.props.modelCheck && <div>{() => this.onModelSelect('displayModel')}</div>}` but again this does nothing?

Comment: In which method you have done {this.props.modelCheck && <div>{() => this.onModelSelect('displayModel')}</div>}? You have to set selectedModal state to show it selected. I don't think you want to show modal.